# sending email recipient using PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

i am not good at php so need some help.I have a php page with check box from where i am trying to send mail to multiple recipient. i can send mail but with little problem. when i select eg. 3 check box to send email  then 1st email recipient is ok but 2nd email goes with 1st and 2nd recipient and 3rd email goes 1st,2nd,3rd recipient. i guess having problem with 'foreach'. will someone pls help me to send individual email to individual recipient with my MySQL query's.

Here is my code for mail.php page

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');


<html>
<head>
<title>PHPMailer - SMTP basic test with authentication</title>
</head>
<body>


include("Connections/connection.php");
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Dublin');

require_once('php_mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from withinclass.phpmailer.php   if not already loaded

$mail = new PHPMailer();


//$body = file_get_contents('contents.php');
//$body = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$sender_name        =   $_SESSION['sender_name'];
$sender_email       =   $_SESSION['sender_email'];
$sender_password    =   $_SESSION['sender_password'];


$id_user    =   $_POST["id_user"];

foreach ($id_tariff as $idt)
{
$query = sprintf("SELECT From_Date, To_Date, first, last, city, country, Email_1, Email_2, account_name FROM user_info where id_user = $id_user");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


$body = "
<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3' bordercolor='#ffcccc'>
<tr>
<th bgcolor='#cc3333'>From</th>
<th bgcolor='#cc3333'>To</th>
<th bgcolor='#cc3333'>First Name</th>
<th bgcolor='#cc3333'>Last Name</th>
<th bgcolor='#cc3333'>City</th>

<th bgcolor='#cc3333'>country</th>

</tr>


";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$body .="<tr>";
$body .="<td>".$row['From_Date']."</td>";
$body .="<td bgcolor='#FFE8E8'>".$row['To_Date']."</td>";
$body .="<td>".$row['first']."</td>";
$body .="<td bgcolor='#FFE8E8'>".$row['last']."</td>";
$body .="<td>".$row['city']."</td>";
$body .="<td bgcolor='#FFE8E8'>".$row['country']."</td>";
$body .="</tr>";
$to1 = $row['Email_1'];
$to2 = $row['Email_2'];
$account_name = $row['account_name'];
}
$body .="</table>";


$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
// 1 = errors and messages
// 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username = "$sender_email"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password = "$sender_password"; // SMTP account password


$mail->SetFrom($sender_email,$sender_name);

$mail->AddReplyTo("$sender_email","$sender_name");


$mail->Subject = "Hello Dear $account_name";


$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";

$mail->MsgHTML($body);



$mail->AddAddress($to1,$account_name);

$mail->AddAddress($to2,$account_name);




if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "YOUR E-MAIL HAS SENT";

}


}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The code you show is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use the proper sanitation method of your library (like `mysql_real_escape_string()` for the classic mysql library), or switch to PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: you did not say what is your problem with foreach. did you try to echo the foreach results

Comment: Yeah, this needs more and better info.

Comment: I'm not following your questions completely, but why do you only have $to1 and $to2 defined? It seems like your missing one

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `$mail->ClearAddresses()` after each mail goes out. You're not resetting the PHPMailer object after each mail, and AddAddress() does exactly what it says - adds a new address to the 'To:' list.

Comment: Hello Marc B, many thanks for your reply.
i just put this in here. its not working for me. however i got another solution. i just called $mail = new PHPMailer(); just after while loop. and its working.



if(!$mail->Send()) {
$mail->ClearAddresses();
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "YOUR E-MAIL HAS SENT";

}

Comment: that makes no sense. "if the mail fails to send, clear the addresses", which means that if the mail goes out ok, you're still going to be sending duplicates. You should clear the addresses unconditionally before starting the loop over again.